# Launching Eclipse Embedded Maven commands from outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

assuming my Eclipse uses an 'internal' Maven, located in the path: *C:\Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.6.2.20150902-0001*

How can I launch from the system console commands that use that EMBEDDED Maven?

Specifically, to launch a class packA.packB.MyClass and its dependencies to load correctly.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot use the internal Maven of Eclipse on the command line.

You need to get a command line Maven as well and use that.